# GO_BLOCK in WHEN_VALIDATE Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I'm working with oracle forms. I've a procedure I have to run whenever a specific field's value is modified. The procedure I have to execute contains a go_block instruction, which can't be used in the when_validate_item trigger. Is there anyway to bypass this?

EDIT

I have to use the when_validate_item, because the procedure I have to run has to be run when the field is modified, BUT BEFORE the validation is executed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usually there is a restriction on using `GO_BLOCK` or `GO_ITEM` on a `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM`. However there are a couple of ways to overcome this. One way is to use a `WHEN-TIMER-EXPIRED` trigger. Here is how-

`WHEN-TIMER-EXPIRED`

```
Begin    
if GET_APPLICATION_PROPERTY(TIMER_NAME) = 'NEW_TIMER' then    
   CALL_PROG_UNIT(); --This is your Procedure that calls the GO_BLOCK   
   /*Do rest of validation here*/
end if;
END;
```

`WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM`

```
DECLARE    
  timer_id TIMER;    
Begin        
  timer_id := CREATE_TIMER('NEW_TIMER',1,NO_REPEAT);    --set a short timer so that the WHEN-TIMER-EXPIRED trigger is fired immediately
End;
```

What happens is - This will create & expire the timer as soon as the `CREATE_TIMER` function is called and then the form level trigger `WHEN-TIMER-EXPIRED` will check the expired timer name and call your program unit that has the `GO_BLOCK`. Hope this helps.

---

**UPDATE**

Mr [Jeffery Kemp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103295/jeffrey-kemp) wanted to see proof that this solution works. So here it is-

An Oracle form with two Blocks `BLOCK1` and `BLOCK2` with text items on it

[image]

W-V-I Trigger

[image]

W-T-E Form Trigger. This calls a PROGRAM UNIT `P_CALL_PROC` with `GO_BLOCK` function call first and then does some validations on the field `Number 2`.

[image]

Here is `P_CALL_PROC`

[image]

And here is the result-

[image]

And

[image]

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8vcLCRp7EA) is a Youtube link to see the Form in action.

Comment: Of course, this means that the procedure won't be executed until *after* the validation has been executed. Confused as to why the OP marked this as correct. Not that I have a better suggestion, mind you :)

Comment: Well, you cannot call `go_block` or a `go_item` forms built in function from a `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` item level trigger. This solution places the procedure which calls the `go_block` inside a Form level trigger and that form level trigger is invoked by the `TIMER` function at the item level trigger. Also, there could be additional validation or processing inside the procedure which will be executed when called, not sure if there is a problem there (i've used this in numerous forms and it works ;) Hence, The solution works that's why it was marked as correct.

Comment: Please read my comment again. Just because it executes without error doesn't mean it solves the *problem as stated* - i.e. the desire to run some code BEFORE the validation has been executed. This is not a solution to the OP's *stated problem*. Whether his stated problem is his *actual* problem, of course, is another question entirely.

Comment: Mr. Kemp, if you have a better solution then please post an answer here (you are welcome to do so). As for the validation after the Procedure call is concerned, I have modified the answer to your satisfaction. And yes, I stand by my recommendation that it works and solves the problem.

Comment: No, Annjawn: simply reducing the timer to the minimum time delay *does not do what you think it does*. The timer will not execute until *after the when-validate-item trigger has finished*. Oracle Forms is not multi-threaded on the client side - you can't have two separate pieces of PL/SQL code running at the same time.

Comment: Also, I don't need to give a "better solution" (as I said, I don't have a better suggestion) - you need to prove that your solution actually does what you say it does. Try it out. Put debug calls in, or log timestamps at the different points in your code (e.g. before and after the CREATE_TIMER call, and at the start of the when-timer-expired trigger). You will see that the timer code fires *AFTER* the w-v-i trigger has finished.

Comment: Oh yes, and I agree that the timer code fires after the w-v-i trigger. But as soon as the timer is done, it fires the w-t-e form level trigger which calls the `PROGRAM_UNIT` first and then performs/runs some validation checks on the value of `:Block_name.the_item` on which the w-v-i. This is a sequential process i.e. one after the other, not parallel. And also, if there are any errors in the w-t-e trigger it can very well raise an exception wipe the value of the item field and stop the user from moving forward. And as far as testing goes, this so far works well for me.

Comment: And the solution works for the OP and it works for me too. If it doesn't work for you then you must be doing something wrong. If you don't like the solution you are welcome to find your own and post it as an answer. Again, I think we should just agree to disagree and call it a day.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I have Updated the answer with the "Proof" you seek.

Comment: Thanks, you've proved my point. All you've done is moved the validation code *out of the when-validate-item trigger* and deferred it until the timer expires. It means that the item is marked as valid even though the validation hasn't been run yet. When the w-t-e trigger fails (with raise form_trigger_failure), unless you change the item state yourself, the timer will not mark the item as invalid.

Comment: Even if the w-v-i contains the validation code it can also fail before any of the actual validation code runs, so its true in that case too. Not sure what you mean by "the item is marked as valid even though the validation hasn't been run yet". If the w-t-e trigger can fail, so can the w-v-i trigger. I guess that you are missing the point that this is a "workaround" and works almost exactly as validating an item using w-v-i with the only exception of the ability of using `go_block` function before(after or while) performing the validation. Plain and simple, working, and hence proved :)

Comment: `The item is marked as valid even though the validation hasn't been run yet` - My item is not validated until the code in w-t-e runs to validate it. Ofcourse, the w-v-i is a builtin to validate an item, but I can validate an item any which way I like to as long as the validation process is triggered by the w-v-i trigger (or by any other means as well).

Comment: No, there is a big difference between w-v-i failing and w-t-e failing. If the w-v-i fails, the item remains marked as "invalid". If the w-t-e fails, *after* the w-v-i has succeeded, the item will be "valid", even though your custom validation procedure failed. Yes, I agree this is a workaround, but I'm pointing out a potential problem with it, mainly that the validation routine works differently if it is not called from within the context of a w-v-i trigger.

Comment: Also, your statement "my item is not validated until the code in w-t-e runs to validate it" is only your perspective on it, not Oracle Forms'. Oracle Forms considers the item to have been validated if the item is marked valid, e.g. after the w-v-i trigger is fired and completes without raising an exception.

Comment: The proof in the pudding is that even if your w-t-e fails, the user will be able to save the record (along with the invalid values) - *unless* you add extra code elsewhere (e.g. calling the validation routine again from the pre-commit trigger or something like that).

Comment: A simple way to handle that is in the exception block of w-t-e `:BLOCK.item := NULL;`. For a more complicated w-t-e, some global params can come in handy too.

Comment: Another way (which means the user gets to see what their data was, instead of disappearing straight away) is to do this: `:BLOCK.item := :BLOCK.item;` - depends on user requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the POST-CHANGE trigger.

Comment: I have to run the process before the validation process kicks in.

Comment: "Post-Change Trigger
Legal Commands
SELECT statements, unrestricted built-ins"

Answer (score 0):

When I have been running into this kind of problems I usually have been able to fix the problem with rewriting and/or redesigning the form itself. In other words why do you need to use a procedure that moves the focus to another item before the validation?

To be able to work around this kind of problem I should recommend you to read through the Forms help to learn which triggers have issue with restricted builtins. With enough knowledge how the forms it working you should be able to solve most of these kind of problems. On the rare cases where I have not been able to work around the problem I have used the timer workaround.

Comment: What if you are given an existing form with lots of code, program units and logic on it already and asked to add a functionality to it where you have come across having have to call `go_block` inside a `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM`, would you re-design the entire form then?

Comment: I have been working with legacy forms that originally was designed in Forms 3 (some in Forms 2)  meaning that I know that this is not an easy task. What I meant is that if you truly understand the business need and how forms is working then you usually can work around the problem with restricted builtins. In some cases that may not be possible and then as a final resort you can use the timer trick to get around the problem.