# Select records fillin a field on a block (Oracle Forms)

Tags: forms, oracle, select

I have a block from a table.

I want that I fill the code field with a number, and select the record with these number on their id. I want to use the when-validate-item on the code field, I don't know how "select" the wanted record on oracle forms. Any idea?

Sorry my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll be easier if you have two blocks on your form:

1. A single-record control block (e.g. `SEARCH_BLK`) with the code field (e.g. `CODE`) that will act as a "search" field, as well as a "Search" button.
2. A second block based on your database table (e.g. `MYTABLE`) which will show the record. Add a predicate for the block's DEFAULT_WHERE property, e.g. `ID = :SEARCH_BLK.CODE`.

Your when-button-pressed trigger on your Search button would then have something like:

```
GO_BLOCK('MYTABLE');
EXECUTE_QUERY;
```

Note that you can't call the GO_BLOCK builtin from a when-validate-item trigger.

If you *really* want to have it done from when-validate-item, you can use the timer trick, described here: [GO_BLOCK in WHEN_VALIDATE Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608330/go-block-in-when-validate-trigger)